# Flutter Error : await tester.pumpWidget((MyApp());

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying some flutter features and I'm getting an error in my `widget_test.dart` file and I'm stuck.

Here is the `Widget_test.dart` file code:

```
void main()
 {
      testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  
    await tester.pumpWidget((MyApp());

    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);

  });
}
```

Comment: this is a default test code for Counter App, you might have renamed `MyApp()` to something else. You can just delete the content of this test file if you don't need testing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

by default flutter will create this test as an example but you can delete it.